# Rspec: deprecation warning

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I created a following rspec mock which runs fine but i get the warning when i execute it.

```
Using `stub` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead. called from /file/path.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'.
```

Here is my unit test. Line 26 is       `user_health_condition.stub(:user_condition_flag) do |user_id|` in my unit test. Per warning i am using expect so why i am getting this warning?

```
describe '.user_condition_flag' do
  let(:expected_result_with_diabetes) { 'Y' }
  let(:expected_result_without_diabetes) { 'N' }
  let(:user_id_1) { 38 }
  let(:user_id_2) { 39 }

  context 'with entries in table' do
    it 'returns expected results' do
      user_health_condition = double(user_health_condition)
      allow(user_health_condition).to receive(:user_condition_flag).and_return(expected_result_with_diabetes)
      user_health_condition.stub(:user_condition_flag) do |user_id|
        if user_id == :user_id_1
          'Y'
        elsif user_id == :user_id_2
          'N'
        end
      end

      expect(user_health_condition.user_condition_flag(:user_id_1)).to eq(expected_result_with_diabetes)
      expect(user_health_condition.user_condition_flag(:user_id_2)).to eq(expected_result_without_diabetes)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 12):

To elaborate on @Brad's answer with specifics in case the [link](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/using-stub-from-rspecmocks-old-should-syntax-without-explicitly-enabling-the-syntax-is-deprecated) dies at one point

> `allow(User).to receive(:find_by).and_return(user)` instead of this:
>
> `User.stub(:find_by).and_return(user)`

Replace

```
user_health_condition.stub(:user_condition_flag) do
```

With

```
allow(user_health_condition).to receive(:user_condition_flag) do
```